# Proving SQL Database is in 3NF by identifying functional dependencies

Tags: sql, database, functional-programming, dependencies, 3nf

Having the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE venues(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME TEXT,
    address TEXT
    );

CREATE TABLE movies(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    title TEXT,
    YEAR INT);

CREATE TABLE genres(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME TEXT,
    description TEXT
    );

CREATE TABLE movies_genres(
    movie_id INT REFERENCES movies(id),
    genre_id INT REFERENCES genres(id)
    );

CREATE TABLE actors(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME TEXT
    );

CREATE TABLE movies_actors(
    movie_id INT REFERENCES movies(id),
    actor_id INT REFERENCES actors(id)
    );

CREATE TABLE screenings(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    venue_id INT REFERENCES venues(id),
    movie_id INT REFERENCES movies(id),
    DATE TEXT,
    TIME TEXT
    );

CREATE TABLE sold_tickets(
    screening_id INT REFERENCES screenings(id),
    ROW INT NOT NULL,
    seat INT NOT NULL,
    unique(screening_id, ROW, seat)
    );
```

- written in syntax for PostgreSQL, how can one prove this database is in third normal form (3NF) by identifying the functional dependencies ? X -> Y

I'm thinking that maybe an approach of sequentially proving the database is in 1NF, then 2NF, then 3NF would be good, however I'm not sure how those functional dependencies would look like on this tables.

Thank you

Comment: *"I'm thinking that maybe an approach of sequentially proving the database is in 1NF, then 2NF, then 3NF would be good . . ."* No, all you have to do is prove every relation (every table) is in 3NF. Any relation that's in 3NF is also, by definition, in 2NF and 1NF.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your question boils down to this: How do you derive functional dependencies from a SQL database (or SQL schema, or SQL table)?

First, look at the unique constraints (`primary key`, `unique`, `unique index`, etc. The unique constraints give you the left-hand side of a functional dependency. For example, in

```
CREATE TABLE venues(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME TEXT,
    address TEXT
    );
```

the FD id->NAME, address holds. NAME->address and address->NAME do not hold. The table permits this kind of data.  Should it?

```
id  NAME     address
--
1   Wilton Stage   123 Main St
2   Wilton Jazz    321 Main St
3   Wilton Stage   123 Main St
4   Wilton Patio   123 Main St
5   Hayes Lounge   123 Main St
6   Wilton Stage   124 Main St
```

Some of your tables have no unique constraints. That's a problem for you.

Some tables should have more than one unique constraint. In the table above, you *probably* need a unique constraint on name, on address, or on the pair.